# Shop for process data acquisition equipment and software

Tags: electrical-engineering, software

I have used the Dataq products for brief data studies to troubleshoot equipment on a manufacturing environment. I am now considering a project to watch pressures, signals and other data collected from processes and issue warnings or alarms if certain conditions happen.

For instance, we are currently logging 5 channels at 100 times/second. These are pressures from pressure sensors on a pump system. We want to start issuing warnings if a pressure spikes over a certain level for more than 0.1 seconds. There are other conditions as well.

My question is what company do you have experience with when it comes to hardware and software? It seems like I could spend 100 hours creating software to do a task like a moving box standard deviation or average, rate of change or other functions to avoid spending 1k or 2k on some nice prewritten tools. I am proficient in C#.

I'd rather not:

- reinvent the wheel.
- buy into a lousy system because it has slick website
- pay an arm and a leg.

Answer (score 1):

1. One of the best and proven method is the do a google search for local test and measurement companies in your area. A good search string to use is [data acquisition hardware and software development companies](https://millionshort.com/search?keywords=data%20acquisition%20hardware%20and%20software%20development%20companies&remove=0&shopping=&country=&chat=). I used the [millionshort](https://millionshort.com/) search engine because it removes all sponsored results.
2. Another proven method is talk to colleagues in your industry (Networking) in your local area. They can provide insight into cost, time to market, skill level, and reputation.
3. Another effective method is perform [data acquisition hardware and software development engineer](https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data%20acquisition%20hardware%20and%20software%20development%20engineer&l=Colorado&vjk=adb501dc0f4b8fb1) job search engine like indeed. This should give list of companies in your area.
4. Sometimes effective is to talk to a local manufacture sales representative in your area.

[Labview](https://www.ni.com/en-us/shop/labview/labview-details.html) from [National Instrument](https://www.ni.com/en-us.html) is very good shrink wrapped software package that uses graphical programming that is fully capable of achieving your goal. National Instruments also has a [partner network](https://partners.ni.com/directory/search?f0=NI%20Software&f0v0=LabVIEW) that can speed up development. Note: They are not cheap.

National Instruments also has "C" programming language based solution call [LabWindows / CVI](https://www.ni.com/en-us/shop/electronic-test-instrumentation/programming-environments-for-electronic-test-and-instrumentation/what-is-labwindows-cvi.html) that has API's other software development platforms such is Visual Studio development framework.

Below is a possible list of suggested companies that provide similar services and suggested links.

**References:**

1. [Bloomy](https://www.bloomy.com/)
2. [Data Acquisition Hardware & Software](http://www.midwestmeasurement.com/products)
3. [Averna](https://www.averna.com/en/home/)
4. [G Systems](https://www.gsystems.com/why-g-systems)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have spent about 8 - 16 hours searching, reading and reviewing websites of solutions to this. The problem with using websites and sales people as a resource is it doesn't always get you to a good solution. IF the website seems to promise or if the sales person is needing the sale they usually do what they can to sell you. That is why I am posting here. I was hoping that this would be a good source for your #2 suggestion above. I am hoping to get feedback from actual users to get a better understanding. If this is not the right place for that I understand.

Comment: @EricSnyder, Providing straight up recommendation with names, and contact information is a violation of stackexchange policy. Also I can attest that Technology sourcing is very hard and takes time. A final note the websites and sales people will get you closer to the solution, then you have to bring the solution home.

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying that. THat is why I am asking for: "I am hoping to get feedback from actual users"

Comment: @EricSnyder, Bloomy might be good choice, but they are in the east cost and very expensive. NI has good products (Software and Hardware) might be cheaper option.